# Summarise_each and dplyr syntax

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I've been given a set of particularly messy data.  In it there were three columns denoting the same factor variable - focus1, focus2, and focus3 where each observation of the data could contain more than one focus yet they are not a measure of magnitude i.e. the focus given in focus1 is not necessarily a stronger focus than that of focus2.  I need to expand these three variables to indicator variables for each possible level of a consolidated focus variable.  To do this, I used the code below, and it worked perfectly on my PC yesterday but I work on a mac in my office and I am now running into problems.

```
# Create focus variables
spr.focus<- y1 %>%
  gather(foc_num, focus, starts_with("focus")) %>%
  mutate(present = 1) %>%
  spread(focus, present, fill = 0)

# Reorder data on ID var while removing unnecessary columns
spr.focus <- spr.focus[order(spr.focus$tid), -c(34, 54)] 

# Group by ID var and summarise indicator variables to get one obs per ID
focusvars <- spr.focus %>%
  group_by(tid) %>% # tid is id var
  summarise_each(funs(sum), Arts:Unclear)
```

I have run into two problems:

1. summarise_each appears to have been made obsolete on Mac and not Windows?  The answer here appears to be to use summarise_at.  Can I use the same x:y notation for denoting the columns to summarise?  This is important because there are around 20-30 columns between the first and last index.
2. For some reason R no longer recognises column names I refer to within the pipe notation.  I get an error "*Error in eval_bare(dot$expr, dot$env) : object 'Arts' not found*".

I'm also quite curious, what is causing these disparities between operating on Windows and Mac?  I have to imagine it is different versions of packages/RStudio itself but it is creating quite a conundrum.

Comment: It might be that there are different versions of dplyr on the two computers. In any case, you could use `summarise_at` (and select the columns to summarize using the same methods as for `select`) if you want to choose specific columns to summarize, or `summarise_all` if you're summarizing all the non-grouping columns. Or, you could summarize before (or without) spreading, e.g., `y1 %>%
  gather(foc_num, focus, starts_with("focus")) %>% group_by(tid, focus) %>% summarise(n = n(), sum=sum(focus))`

Comment: @eipi10 what it the n = n() part of your summarise statement?  That code by itself threw an error.  I thought the mutate statement was a key part of the whole process because it creates the numbers to be able to be summarised.  The focus variables are character vectors describing what the focus was.

Comment: `n()` is just a convenience function in `dplyr` that counts the number of rows in each group. I was assuming focus1, focus2, etc. were values that you wanted to sum for each group. I threw in the row-count as well, just for illustration. Are you just trying to count the number of observations? You can do that with `n()`, or `tally`, or with the base R `length` function. It will be easier to provide additional help if you include a data sample (paste in the output of `dput(data_sample)`.

Comment: No I'm trying to create indicator variables for each possible category of the focus variable.  The problem was that the focus variable was split into 3 separate variables.  I appreciate the help but I've actually solved the problem with the code in the edit above!  Thank you

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: So your solution was to remove the information?  That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering with summarize_at, I found my solution:

```
focusvars <- spr.focus %>%
  group_by(tid) %>% # tid is an id var
  summarise_at(vars(Arts:Unclear),funs(sum))
```

For some reason, it still throws errors in the margin that cannot find colnames in scope but it creates the new dataframe. I'll leave this up in case this is helpful to others.